# A problem on linear transformation and invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $T$ is a linear transformation of rank one on a finite dimensional vector space, I have to check whether the statement "$I-T$ is invertible" is true or not ?

Now suppose $I-T$ is invertible then $\exists x$ $x-T(x)=0$ requires $T(x)=0$.

Comment: If $x-T(x)=0$ then $T(x) = I(x) = x$, so the argument falls over at this point

Answer (score 1):

If $T=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $I_2-T$ is invertible. If $T=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $I_2-T$ isn't invertible.

If $T=[1]$, then $I_1-T\color{grey}{=[0]}$ isn't invertible.

Comment: @sosha Do you still require help with this?